# UITextField crashes on type

Tags: objective-c, ios, crash, uitextfield

I have a UITextField initted from a xib file. For some reason, it crashes on the second key I type ( or the first number, for some reason ).
EDIT: forgot to mention, it crashes with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS. NSZombieEnabled=YES doesn't change anything. there's no code to show, as it's only the xib file. This is the backtrack:

```
#0  0x011d9000 in objc_assign_ivar ()
#1  0x031f2c34 in -[AppleSpell init] ()
#2  0x00384538 in -[UITextChecker _checker] ()
#3  0x00385de9 in -[UITextChecker checkSpellingOfString:startingAt:language:wrap:correction:] ()
#4  0x0c01f725 in TIInputManagerZephyr::lookup_spellcheck_candidates ()
#5  0x0c01f3f3 in TIInputManagerZephyr::lookup_static_dynamic_candidates ()
#6  0x0c01cb2b in TIInputManager::lookup ()
#7  0x0c01ce18 in TIInputManager::autocorrection ()
#8  0x0c03406b in -[TIKeyboardInputManagerZephyr autocorrection] ()
#9  0x0016cbe8 in -[UIKeyboardImpl generateCandidatesWithCompletions:] ()
#10 0x0016cc3b in -[UIKeyboardImpl generateCandidates] ()
#11 0x00179a23 in -[UIKeyboardImpl addInputString:fromVariantKey:] ()
#12 0x0017b71b in -[UIKeyboardImpl handleKeyEvent:] ()
#13 0x002a72ee in -[UIKeyboardLayoutStar sendStringAction:forKey:] ()
#14 0x002abd19 in -[UIKeyboardLayoutStar touchUp:] ()
#15 0x00188da2 in -[UIKeyboardLayout touchesEnded:withEvent:] ()
#16 0x00055ded in -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] ()
#17 0x00036c37 in -[UIApplication sendEvent:] ()
#18 0x0003bf2e in _UIApplicationHandleEvent ()
#19 0x011ef992 in PurpleEventCallback ()
#20 0x00f97944 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()
#21 0x00ef7cf7 in __CFRunLoopDoSource1 ()
#22 0x00ef4f83 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#23 0x00ef4840 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#24 0x00ef4761 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#25 0x011ee1c4 in GSEventRunModal ()
#26 0x011ee289 in GSEventRun ()
#27 0x0003fc93 in UIApplicationMain ()
#28 0x000026c9 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff678) at main.m:15
```

Does anybody know what can cause this/how to fix it?
Tnx in advance!

Comment: you may find your answer here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257175/uitextfield-auto-correction-crash-in-ios-4-3-on-simulator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide more information. Is that the only field crashing your app? Has it always behaved like this?

That said, it looks like it's the autocompletion that's crashing on you. Try disabling autocomplete for that field (IIRC, there's an option for that in Interface Builder).

Comment: [Or disable autocomplete inside the simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257175/uitextfield-auto-correction-crash-in-ios-4-3-on-simulator/6645462#6645462).