# Crash With iOS Private API Call

Tags: objective-c, ios5

This call:

```
[UIKeyboardImpl(ShortcutConversionSupport) _shortcutConversionCandidateForInput:]
```

is crashing my app. Googling and looking through Apple's API documentation brings up no results. I have never seen this call being made anywhere in my app. I also put a break-point at the location I *believe* it is getting called at. Here is the crash report:

(FYI, the crash log could not be completely symbolicated even when using the correct dSYM file. No idea why)

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x327e188f __exceptionPreprocess + 163
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x34837259 objc_exception_throw + 33
2   CoreFoundation                  0x327e1789 +[NSException raise:format:] + 1
3   CoreFoundation                  0x327e17ab +[NSException raise:format:] + 35
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3273bf5b -[__NSCFString substringWithRange:] + 103
5   Buffer                          0x000fa061 0xd6000 + 147553
6   UIKit                           0x32348137 -[UIKeyboardImpl(ShortcutConversionSupport) _shortcutConversionCandidateForInput:] + 615
7   UIKit                           0x32322c07 -[UIKeyboardImpl addInputString:fromVariantKey:] + 287
8   UIKit                           0x32322ae1 -[UIKeyboardImpl handleStringInput:fromVariantKey:] + 165
9   UIKit                           0x32321829 -[UIKeyboardImpl handleKeyEvent:] + 1501
10  UIKit                           0x02b10261 0x2af4000 + 115297
11  UIKit                           0x324bb8a3 -[UIKeyboardLayoutStar sendStringAction:forKey:isPopupVariant:] + 487
12  UIKit                           0x3231fdcd -[UIKeyboardLayoutStar touchUp:] + 3197
13  UIKit                           0x02b2ab47 0x2af4000 + 224071
14  UIKit                           0x3231f0fd -[UIKeyboardLayout touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 381
15  UIKit                           0x3222292b -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 319
16  UIKit                           0x32222319 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 381
17  UIKit                           0x32208695 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 357
18  UIKit                           0x32207f3b _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5827
19  GraphicsServices                0x3188f22b PurpleEventCallback + 883
20  CoreFoundation                  0x327b5523 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 39
21  CoreFoundation                  0x327b54c5 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 141
22  CoreFoundation                  0x327b4313 __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
23  CoreFoundation                  0x327374a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 301
24  CoreFoundation                  0x3273736d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
25  GraphicsServices                0x3188e439 GSEventRunModal + 137
26  UIKit                           0x32236cd5 UIApplicationMain + 1081
27  Buffer                          0x000d8327 0xd6000 + 8999
28  Buffer                          0x000d7dcc 0xd6000 + 7628
```

I understand that is crashing at substringWithRange: but when does this particular ShortcutConversionSupport method get called? I believe that will help me isolate the issue.

Comment: Your crash report is symbolicated. Do you use any custom keyboard?

Comment: Check the solution provided in the thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257175/uitextfield-auto-correction-crash-in-ios-4-3-on-simulator, See if this works for you.

Comment: One thing I didn't mention is that I am unable to reproduce the conditions that cause this crash on my end. This is a customer's crash log. @Dani I wasn't sure as the line (Buffer                          0x000fa061 0xd6000 + 147553) doesn't reference a method call. I thought that was curious. -rishi That doesn't solve the issue. That appears to be a simulator crash only. This is a device side crash. For good measure I did toggle all Apple keyboard options off, tested the app, then turned them all on again with no luck of reproducibility. I'll ask the customer to turn off all keyboard options.

Comment: @Dani I am using an accessory keyboard. But the keyboard itself is the stock software keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the issue:

```
- (UITextRange *)textRangeFromPosition:(UITextPosition *)fromPosition toPosition:(UITextPosition *)toPosition
{    
// Generate IndexedPosition instances that wrap the to and from ranges
    IndexedPosition *from = (IndexedPosition *)fromPosition;
    IndexedPosition *to = (IndexedPosition *)toPosition;  

    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(MIN(from.index, to.index), ABS(to.index - from.index));
    return [IndexedRange rangeWithNSRange:range];    

}
```

More specifically: **ABS(to.index - from.index)**

The issue is that the compiler thinks that the product of this negation is a NSUInteger because to.index and from.index are both NSUInteger variables (so the value can never be negative). Therefore, if from.index > to.index the value would overflow producing a value that is the max size of a 32 bit uint rather than a negative value. Also note, ABS uses **typeof** to determine the return value of the product. This is the fix:

```
- (UITextRange *)textRangeFromPosition:(UITextPosition *)fromPosition toPosition:(UITextPosition *)toPosition
{    
    IndexedPosition *from = (IndexedPosition *)fromPosition;
    IndexedPosition *to = (IndexedPosition *)toPosition;  

    NSInteger index = to.index - from.index;    
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(MIN(from.index, to.index), ABS(index));

    return [IndexedRange rangeWithNSRange:range];

}
```

By the way, this *only* occurs when a user has removed all of the Shortcuts in Settings > General > Keyboard > Shortcuts.